# how can convert hour data to minute data?

Tags: python, keras, data-science

My data is like below (20 data in one day)

i want this hour data(20) to minitue data(20*60 = 1200)

```
    date        number  name          div   a
0   2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  234.0
1   2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  -420.0
2   2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  -318.0
3   2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  -161.0
4   2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  -205.0
5   2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  13.0
6   2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  538.0
7   2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  632.0
8   2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  604.0
9   2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  808.0
10  2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  565.0
11  2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  774.0
12  2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  1292.0
13  2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  927.0
14  2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  1205.0
15  2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  1133.0
16  2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  2229.0
17  2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  1840.0
18  2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  653.0
19  2008-01-01  150.0   서울역(150)    승차  -294.0
20  2008-01-01  151.0   시청(151) 승차  96.0
```

can i convert this hour data to minute data??

i tryed lstm model -> regression model is not working

like below

```
y = p # p is predicted value with lstm model 
x = list(range(len(p)))
x = np.reshape(x, (-1, 1))
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, train_size=.8, shuffle=False)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression() 
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

[image: 1]

Comment: I don't see where the hour data is in the table you provided. I also don't think machine learning will solve your problems here.

Comment: 0~19 is hour data and value is ```a```

Comment: What is your question? Is it about converting the hour column  to minutes, or about predicting the values in the last column?

Comment: After expanding each hourly row into 60 rows, how do you want to distribute each value? dividing by 60? interpolate?

Comment: it's about converting the hour column to minutes and predicting each minutes value

Comment: i want each 60 minute use predict with linear(or nonlinear) regression

Comment: So you want to predict the minute column, using the other features? This question might get more help on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or some other machine learning forum. Post all the code necessary so we can get the same results on our own computers.